# Is the FB Recommendations Bar still in Beta?

Tags: beta, facebook-recommendations

According to the answers here on stackoverflow, this new social plugin (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendationsbar/) was still in Beta a few months ago.

I implemented it and it works great for me as the App administrator and as a test user, but it is not visible for anyone else. FB doc does not clearly indicate if it is ready for prime time (or when it will be going live).

Comment: How funny I found your post. I was just playing around with this plugin as well, as was wondering the same thing as you.